# C# adding a resource error and calling function

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, dll

Hey all i am new at C# and i am trying to add a resource to a .dll file.

It gives me the error of:
[image: dll error]

**Error 1   Source file 'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data\Temporary Projects\bluRemoteProg\Resources\HIDLibrary.dll' could not be opened ('Unspecified error ')  bluRemoteProg**

What am i forgetting to do?

David

**UPDATE**

Got it working but how do i call a function from the form menu? I've tried:

```
PS3_BluMote.PS3RemoteDevice.Connect();
```

and

```
PS3_BluMote.PS3RemoteDevice.Connect();
```

[image: second error]

but that does not seem to work...

Comment: Can you check your DLL is 32-bit or 64-bit ?

Comment: Shouldn't a DLL be added to References, not to Resources?

Comment: Like Emiswelt wrote you need to add dll as reference, not as resource. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) how to do it.

Comment: Ok i finally got it to recognize but how do i call a function (like PS3RemoteDevice("0x054c","0x0306",false)) when i click on a button in the form1?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new project to your solution: e.g. `YourApp.Engine` as a **C# Class Libraray** project, then add your resources to that project (Double-click properties of *YourApp.Engine* project, and click Resources tab).

you can now use your DLL named *YourApp.Engine* everywhere in your app:

```
using YourApp.Engine;
```