# C# create an instance of

Tags: c#, instance, instanceof

New to C# so this is just me guessing at it after reading some tutiroals.

I have a class called PS3RemoteDevice:

```
namespace PS3_BluMote
{
   public class PS3RemoteDevice
   {
```

And from my main form button i try doing this:

```
PS3RemoteDevice PS3R = new PS3RemoteDevice;
PS3R.Connect();
```

But of course, that does not seem to work. A little help since i am a noob would be great!

Thanks!

David

**PS3RemoteDevice.cs code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Timers;
using HIDLibrary;

namespace PS3_BluMote
   {
      public class PS3RemoteDevice
      {
        public event EventHandler<ButtonData> ButtonAction;
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Connected;
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Disconnected;

        private HidDevice HidRemote;
        private Timer TimerFindRemote;
        private Timer TimerHibernation;

        private int _vendorID = 0x054c;
        private int _productID = 0x0306;
        private int _batteryLife = 100;
        private bool _hibernationEnabled = false;


    public PS3RemoteDevice(int VendorID, int ProductID, bool HibernationEnabled)
    {
        if (HibernationEnabled)
        {
            TimerHibernation = new Timer();
            TimerHibernation.Interval = 60000;
            TimerHibernation.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerHibernation_Elapsed);
        }

        _vendorID = VendorID;
        _productID = ProductID;
        _hibernationEnabled = HibernationEnabled;
    }


    public void Connect()
    {
        if (!FindRemote())
        {
            StartRemoteFindTimer();
        }
    }
```

Etc etc....

Comment: You have some syntax errors up there, is that what you are talking about?  Instead of us guessing, you should show us the error.

Comment: PS3RemoteDevice PS3R = new PS3RemoteDevice(); instead? (is it a compile error) if not then Can't really help you unless you show us library code or link us to that library you use

Comment: you are missing the constructor brackets: `new PS3RemoteDevice();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class only has a constructor that takes three parameters:

```
 public PS3RemoteDevice(int VendorID, int ProductID, bool HibernationEnabled) 
 { ... }
```

Just like in any other method call you need to pass those parameters when you instantiate an object with `new`, for example:

```
int vendorId = 5;
int productId = 42;
PS3RemoteDevice PS3R = new PS3RemoteDevice(vendorId, productId, false);
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the rest of the class code,

`PS3RemoteDevice PS3R = new PS3RemoteDevice();` will work, with the parantheses.

Comment: I get the error **Error 1 'PS3_BluMote.PS3RemoteDevice' does not contain a constructor that takes '0' arguments**

Comment: well, if you post the rest of the class code of PS3RemoteDevice, then I can help.

Comment: Ok the constructor takes 3 arguments, and you can't call it with anything other than 3 arguments.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
PS3RemoteDevice PS3R = new PS3RemoteDevice();
```

EDIT (with params):

```
PS3RemoteDevice PS3R = new PS3RemoteDevice(someVendorID, some ProductID, someBoolHibernationEnabled);
```

Comment: I get the error **Error 1 'PS3_BluMote.PS3RemoteDevice' does not contain a constructor that takes '0' arguments**

Comment: then you need to put the parameters into the paranthesis... see edit.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new instances of an object, you are calling its constructor method (constructor for short).  It is like any other method, but it is required that you call it, if it is defined.  The syntax is `new MyObject(... parameters here ...);`.

I searched through your previous questions and found [a screenshot of the code you are using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742810/c-adding-a-resource-error-and-calling-function).  You have a constructor that takes parameters.  These parameters are not defined as optional, so you must provide them.  These are `vendorId`, `productId`, and `hibernationEnabled`.

So your code will be `new PS3RemoteDevice(0x054c, 0x0306, false);`.  Or at least that's what the default values in the screenshot looked like.  Figure out the right values to pass by reading the docs for the code you're using.